# How to work around Hibernate 5 requiring compatible constructor for selected fields?

Tags: hibernate, projection, criteria-api

I have upgrade my application from Hibernate 3 to 5.2.10.
Hibernate's Criteria has been deprecated, so I have modified my code to use JPA criteria.

The problem is that Hibernate requires a specific constructor in the DTO class for the selected fields.

In Hibernate 3 an empty constructor and a getter/setter pair were sufficient to map results into the DTO while using projection and [`setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MyDTO.class))`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer)).

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyDTO> criteria = builder.createQuery(MyDTO.class);
    Root<MyEntity> root = criteria.from(MyEntity.class);
    criteria.multiselect(root.get(MyEntity_.id).get(MyEntityId_.fieldToSelect));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

I got this Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [MyDTODTO]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String [select new MyDTODTO(generatedAlias0.fieldToSelect) from MyEntity as generatedAlias0]
```

According to the javadoc, it is normal :

> If the type of the criteria query is `CriteriaQuery<X>` for some user-defined class X (i.e., a criteria query object created by passing a X class argument to the `createQuery` method), the elements of the list passed to the multiselect method will be passed to the X constructor and an instance of type X will be returned for each row.

I have the same problem if I use:

```
criteria.select(builder.construct(MyDTO.class, field1,.., fieldn)
```

My DTO could be used by different query I don't want to create different constructor for different query.

Have can I avoid having to create a compatible constructor ?

Comment: Hi, @rawadolb, I got the same issue here, did you manage to find anything on this?

Comment: Hi @cingulata.. no i didn't.. i'm using queryDsl to avoid this problem

Comment: could you please share a sample? What about nested objects?

Comment: Two opinions: 1. if two queries select different values, they should not return the same type of object. 2. I find it cleaner anyway to get the result as a List<Object[]> and to map each array to an object explicitly. It makes it safer to refactor the code.

Comment: @cingulata : sorry for the delay in responding. Check my answer here

Answer (score 0):

Finally i'm using QueryDsl framework. It's very easy to use and to integrate in my application.

You should generated Metamodel classes and then you can write easily your request. Please check this example : https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/266.

This is another example with nested object (EjAffaire, EjPartie and EjDebiteur).

```
    QEjAffaire ejAffaire = QEjAffaire.ejAffaire;
    QEjPartie ejPartie = QEjPartie.ejPartie;
    QEjDebiteur ejDebiteur = QEjDebiteur.ejDebiteur;
    return new JPAQueryFactory(getEntityManager()).selectFrom(ejPartie).join(ejPartie.ejAffaire, ejAffaire)
        .join(ejPartie.ejDebiteurs, ejDebiteur)
        .where(ejPartie.id.jpaGrNume.eq(ejSuiDel.getJsdGrNume())
            .and(ejPartie.jpaRcsGrNume.coalesce(ejPartie.id.jpaGrNume).getValue().eq(result))
            .and(ejPartie.jpaRcsMil.eq(ejSuiDel.getJsdRcsMil()).and(ejPartie.jpaRcsStC.eq(ejSuiDel.getJsdRcsStC()))
                .and(ejPartie.jpaRcsChrono.eq(ejSuiDel.getJsdRcsChrono())).and(ejPartie.id.jpaQpC.eq("DF"))
                .and(ejAffaire.jafTaC.eq("J"))
                .and(ejAffaire.jafNonRevelableOn.isFalse().or(ejAffaire.jafNonRevelableOn.isNull())))
            .and(ejDebiteur.jdbFpC.in(getFamPclReduitOn())))
        .orderBy(ejAffaire.jafSaisineD.desc()).orderBy(ejAffaire.jafGreffeD.desc())
        .orderBy(ejAffaire.jafMajD.desc()).orderBy(ejPartie.id.jpaNo.asc()).fetchFirst();
```